# Hadamard (Schur) Product

Tags: linear-algebra, hadamard-product

I need to show that hadamard (schur) product $ A \circ B$ can be positive definite even if not both A and B are positive definite. It would be nice to see a simple example which prooves this.

I know that According to Schur Product Theorem, if both A and B are positive definite, then their hadamard (schur) product $ A \circ B$ is also positive definite.

Comment: We usually write Hadamard's name with a capital H. Schur's also.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Consider the $1\times1$ matrices $A=(-1)$ and $B=(-1)$.

Comment: Any example for 2x2 matrix will be appreciated

Comment: Consider $A=\begin{pmatrix}-1&0\\0&-1\end{pmatrix}$ and $B=\begin{pmatrix}-1&0\\0&-1\end{pmatrix}$. You can construct examples of all sizes, as you see!